# Xamarin Forms no longer deploying AppIcon in Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.10.0

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, uno-platform

It appears Visual Studio 2019 Preview 16.10.0 is not deploying the AppIcon to iOS. This is the case for the emulator, a physical device and the archive.  Unfortunately I had to upgrade to fix another issue, and now I can't deploy my App to the AppStore because I get the error: 'Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone...'.

I can highlight the issue in a new project by carrying out the following steps on both versions of VS:

1. Open a new instance of visual studio 2019
2. Create a new Xamarin Forms project (untick Android)
3. Open Assets Catalogs -> Assets
4. Confirm there are default Xamarin Icons in the project's AppIcon node:
   [Default Xamarin Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0dto.png)
5. Run on emulator:

a. On VS 16.10.0:
[Icon missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObvKP.png)

b. On VS 16.8.0:
[Icon present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soNiX.png)

Unfortunately downgrading is not currently an option and the above test (16.8.0) was carried out on a friends PC. Does anyone know of a workaround for this issue?  I've tried googling it but I can find anything.

Comment: have you reported this issue to MS?

Comment: @Jason, I have now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Timd6555 If have create thread at github about this problem, please share the link here.

Comment: Here is the issue on Microsoft's Developer Community site (currently triaged): https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Forms-no-longer-deploying-AppIco/1396907

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I verified contents.json was correct, I verified info.plist was correct and the csproj file as well.  This is frustrating.  I have an app that is released and getting ready to update- but now am not able to- until it is fixed.  Hopefully someone has a workaround- and posts it - or it is fixed.

Comment: I copied the entire project over to my Mac and installed vs on my mac.  At first the simulators did not show up- but on a tip I saw- I created a blank xamarin project and it had the simulators.  I then went back into my project and ran it.  I had to reboot the simulator for the icon to show up when switching between apps in the simulator.  No where near ideal- and really annoying- but it works and allows me to keep moving.

Comment: One thing I noticed is after this update, my Colors.colorset which has a contents.json now had the default values when you first create it.  Just a point- not sure why that happened and if it is related.

Comment: There was an issue opened with Microsoft.  They say there is a fix but it missed the update to 16.10.1 but it should be in 16.10.2.  You can read about it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Xamarin-Forms-no-longer-deploying-AppIco/1396907 and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Cant-deliver-to-the-appstore-since-last/1436223#T-N1445242

Answer (score 0):

For anyone encountering this error. Here's the workaround that I've tried. I opened my Info.plist via XML Editor and found that my CFBundleIconName value is "Icon" as shown on the image below. Had to go to Assets.x cassets and rename App Icon into "Icon". And the icon finally showed.

[image]

By the way I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.4

Comment: Hi. Can you show the correct info.plist?